# ASP MVC 3 - Jquery Ajax always sending Options not Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, asp.net-mvc-3, rest

I have a simple javascript ajax request:

```
$("#login-submit").button().click(function() {
                var ajaxOptions = {
                    url: "http://localhost:29097/authentication/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $("login-form").serialize(),
                    success: function(result) { $("body").html(result); }
                };
                $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
            });
```

However whenever I send off the request, it always sends an OPTIONS request, not the specified POST request. After reading into it more it seems like it *may* be down to cross site posting. I have added a custom action filter in my MVC app which checks for OPTION requests and responds with an "Allow" header specifying "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" although it never seems to do a follow up POST request... Am I missing something here?

The request (tried this in Firefox, Chrome):

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:29097/authentication/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:29097
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: null
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
```

The response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Sun, 19 Jun 2011 16:20:41 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Allow: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

I am sending back the 401 request myself through MVC, as it seemed like it would be the best header to use to indicate that the users credentials were invalid. Could this status code be causing any problems?

Comment: What does it do if you respond with a 200 instead of 401?  Seems to me that an error response is not very likely to work.

Comment: @Pointy - Same thing, it just returns and no followup request is made. This problem all started when I was making a simple ASPMVC RESTful web service and whenever I called it with Jquery Ajax the parameters were not auto binding and were always null. That lead to me noticing that the headers didnt contain any post information because it was an OPTIONS request, and as it is not following up on the OPTIONS with a POST once it gets the response I am a bit lost as to what else I can do... I am sure this must be doable though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a browser that implements [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).  To support this your server needs to respond to the OPTIONS request with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: Isnt that included in the response I have posted above? I have also tried including Access-Control-Allow-Methods, but that didnt work and somewhere else I saw a post saying to just try "allow", tried it with both... still no luck

Comment: @somemvcperson  You're right it is.  The spec I linked to should provide all the guidance you need as to what headers are needed in this particular situation.

Comment: I have tried all of the appropriate headers and no such luck :( I have been doing more research and apparently you just cannot do a client side xmlHttpRequest to another domain: http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/same-origin-policy  I find it really hard to believe that you cannot set your server up to accept XSS if you REALLY know what you are doing... What use is a web service if you can only consume it from your own domain?  Only alternatives I can see are JSONP, Server Proxy, Flash Proxy... all of them seem to ruin the reason for having a clean web service...

Comment: @somemvcperson  Did you see the suggestion on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452519/firefox-3-cors-xmlhttprequest-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: Given this the answer, as CORS is definately the right direction to go for this sort of stuff.